# .Bat file to move file by file extension and substring file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am new with .bat script. I am  trying to create a .bat file for Windows that will allow me to move only pdf files that contain the substring "A20".

In my example any file is moved,  I don't understand what is wrong.

```
@echo off
echo %1|find ".pdf" >nul
if errorlevel 0 (
    echo %1|find "A20" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (move C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\source\%1 C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\destination_A20\%1)
) else (
    echo notfound
)
```

When I run the script, any file is moved. I need to move only pdf files when file name contains "A20"

How can I do that?

Comment: When using the `IF ERRORLEVEL` syntax, it is checking if the errorlevel is geater than or equal to X.  So `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` will basically by TRUE for everything.  Not to many base windows commands that put out a negative errorlevel.  From the help file **ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                    returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                    specified.**

Comment: Side note: do you not think it would be easier to copy and paste the text from the console window into your question then trying to upload a screenshot?

Comment: @Squashman  I keep in mind your recommendation for a next opportunity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options for you.  You can use the command modifiers to isolate the file extension.  You can then use string substitution to see if A20 exists within the base file name.  You can read about the modifiers by reading the HELP for the `CALL` command and you can read about string substitution by reading the help for the `SET` command.

```
set "filename=%~n1"
IF /I "%~x1"==".pdf" (
    IF NOT "%filename:A20=%"=="%filename%" (
        move "C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\source\%~nx1" "C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\destination_A20\"
    ) else (
        echo File is is a PDF but A20 not found
    )
) else (
    echo file is not a PDF
)
```

If you just wanted to do a simple move from one directory to another you could just use wildcards.

```
move "C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\source\*A20*.pdf" "C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\destination_A20\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findstr instead.

```
@echo off
echo %1|findstr /i /c:".pdf" >nul
if errorlevel 0 (
    echo %1|findstr /i /c:"A20" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (move C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\source\%1 C:\Users\Jesus\Downloads\destination_A20\%1)
) else (
    echo notfound
)
```

Comment: I got the same result, any file is moved. I want to move only pdf file that contains A20 in file name